# Using Selenium to select button without unique identifiers or with events

Tags: python, selenium

There's an edit button for a data range selection. The image has an event tied to it. When pressed, the date selection turns on and off. I can determine if the date selection is already open, but I need to open it if it's not. How do I select the edit button between listings? Using Selenium and Python.

This world is new to me, so feel free to explain it if I'm completely off here.

```
if not driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.DayPicker-wrapper'):
     # Select edit button here to open DayPicker
```

Listing 1:
[image]

Listing 2:
[image]

Comment: Looks like you presented here irrelevant element HTML.
Can you share a link of that page?

Comment: I think all the answers you need are there: https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by looking for a static, previous text. Text isn't prefered since it can change, but this is a listing site, and the assets can only be called one thing.

The main challenge is that the class changes for each listing, so I can't just use the same class each time.

I wrote a script to find the static text that was always before the button I wanted, then use `next` to find the class of the button.

```
rental_text = page.find(text="Rental")
button = rental_text.next.find_all('svg')[0]
button_class = button.attrs['class'][0]
edit_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name(button_class)
edit_button.click()
```

Answer (score 0):

Those are svg elements, you can locate them by using xpath. See below :

```
//*[local-name()='svg' @class='jss496']
```

or

```
//*[name()='svg' @class='jss1189']
```

Comment: The jss reference changes for each listing, so I'm trying to find a way to generalize it. I won't know the jss unless I manually open the URL and code for it.